# how to convert c toHex method to java

Tags: java, android, c

Does anyone know how to convert blow code snippet to java code?
Thanks.

```
void
rawdata_to_hex (const unsigned char *rawdata, char *hex_str, int n_bytes)
{
    static const char hex[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n_bytes; i++) {
        unsigned int val = *rawdata++;
        *hex_str++ = hex[val >> 4];
        *hex_str++ = hex[val & 0xf];
    }
    *hex_str = '\0';
}
```

I am using below code, but looks like it is not correct.

```
public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf == null) return "";
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2 * buf.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            appendHex(result, buf[i]);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private final static String HEX = "0123456789abcdef";
    private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
        sb.append(HEX.charAt((b >> 4) & 0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b & 0x0f));
    }
```

My question is how to covert that? anyone can help?

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, I did, and it is correct.

Comment: I if the output of your function is correct, you should make that clear in your question.

Comment: sorry, actually I not quite sure if that is correct

Comment: Still, it's part of the question. Make that clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using methods below works for me

```
/**
 * Convert byte to Hexadecimal
 *
 * @param bytes
 * @return
 */
private static String toHex(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, bytes);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (bytes.length * 2) - hex.length();
    if (paddingLength > 0) {
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
    } else {
        return hex;
    }
}
```

or another way

```
public static String toHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        buff.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    return buff.toString();
}
```